# Copy files to azure blob storage using bitbucket pipeline yml script

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, bitbucket-pipelines

We are trying to copy the source files from bitbucket to Azure blob container through bitbucket pipeline by following the below syntax (Advanced example):

https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/azure-storage-deploy/src/master/README.md?_ga=2.125236490.1078830649.1583361198-1461322304.1571236371

azcopy --quiet --source "ax/file.html" --destination "https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/test/file.html" --dest-sas "$AZURE_STORAGE_SAS_TOKEN"[2020/**/** **:**:**][ERROR] Error parsing destination location "https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/test/file.html": Invalid location 'https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/test/file.html', address could not be parsed. For more details, please type "azcopy --help destination" or use verbose option --verbose.✖ Deployment failed

While copying the file contents from the source folder, we are facing the following error.

We have checked the syntax, file location and everything seems to be alright.

Can anyone debug this and mention the error precisely?

Answer (score 0):

I have got rid of the above error by declaring the source and the destination values in a variables and then calling it from the repository variables in the pipeline yml script.